# Passportjs _userproperty undefined

Tags: express, passport.js

I am using Express + Passport to build a website with signin and signup. It has been working fine util recently a error came up. It occurs when I try to call req.login or req.logout which are the middlewares Passport should have provided.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_userProperty' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.req.logout.req.logOut (D:\Workspace\Github\fyp-web\node_modules\passport-local\node_modules\passport-oauth\node_modules\passport\lib\passport\http\request.js:62:41)
    at D:\Workspace\Github\fyp-web\routes\user.js:29:7
    at callbacks (D:\Workspace\Github\fyp-web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)
    at param (D:\Workspace\Github\fyp-web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
    at pass (D:\Workspace\Github\fyp-web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (D:\Workspace\Github\fyp-web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (D:\Workspace\Github\fyp-web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
    at next (D:\Workspace\Github\fyp-web\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
    at next (D:\Workspace\Github\fyp-web\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:192:9)
    at Object.app.use.express.errorHandler.dumpExceptions [as handle] (D:\Workspace\Github\fyp-web\app.js:143:3)
```

And below is the line in the library which'd gone wrong:

```
req.logIn = function(user, options, done) {
  .....
  var property = this._passport.instance._userProperty || 'user';
```

I believe I've configured the middleware,strategy and route part correctly since there was not error last time. But to play safe, I will attach those code snippet here:

```
//in app.js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.cookieParser(env.server_secret));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.session({ secret:env.server_secret,cookie: { maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24 }}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//in config_passport.js
/* Local strategy */
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
{
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
},
function(email, password, done) {
  Users.isValidUserPassword(email, password, done);
}
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figure it out myself.

The problem is caused by me doing this in my app.js:

```
//app.js
req._passport = passport;
```

I want to pass the passport instance by attaching it to all request. It caused me troubles because passport itself is using "_passport". If you look at the code that went wrong, you'll see:

```
//request.js in passport node_module/passport/lib/http/request.js 
var property = 'user';
if (this._passport && this._passport.instance) {
  property = this._passport.instance._userProperty || 'user';
}
```

So I kind of overwrote passport's code. That's why the "this._passport" is not defined.

Hope this helps others who encounter the same problem.